# Evaluating dates in a DVWP

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I'm trying to evaluate 2 dates in my DVWP, @StartDate (date and time field) and ddwrt:Today().  My expression looks like this:

```
<xsl:when>
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@StartDate) ,1033 ,'M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss') &lt;= ddwrt:Today()">Closed</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@TotalSeats = 0">Unlimited Seating</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@TotalSeats - @FilledSeats = 0 and @TotalSeats != 0">Currently Full</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@TotalSeats - @FilledSeats &gt; 0 and @TotalSeats != 0"><xsl:value-of select="@TotalSeats - @FilledSeats" /> Seats Available</xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:when>
```

My issue is the initial when test vever evaluates correctly even though the dates and times are in the correct format from what I can tell.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I normally tend to do is convert the dates to YYYYMMDD format for both the @StartDate and the Today(), that way they're 8 digit numbers which I then compare.

Comment: The hours are important in this, which is causing me grief I think.

Comment: Ah, even YYYMMDDHHmm is out then, as that'd be 12 digits long and I think it only supports 32bit integers (2^32 is a 10-digit number). Try your method but get ddwrt:TodayISO() ?

Comment: I can do ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string (@StartDate) ,1033 ,'yyMMddHHmm') and that seems to work, when I try with ddwrt:TodayISO(), the web part bombs out, even though it's inherantly in the same format as @StartDate with no formatting.

Comment: You'll need to wrap Today() in a formatdatetime too, `ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(ddwrt:Today()),1033,'yyMMddHHmm')`

Comment: I am, I meant that I'm using the excat same code except in place of @StartDate, I've used ddwrt:TodayISO().  The DVWP renders with the generic Unable to view this web part error.

Comment: Ah, with Today() it works!

Answer (score 3):

YYYMMDDHHmm should work, per James' suggestion in the comments above. Remember that XSL operates on text values, not binary values.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Modified) ,1033 ,'yyyyMMdd HHmmss')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(ddwrt:TodayIso()) ,1033 ,'yyyyMMdd HHmmss')"/>
```

Those are the two values you need. Unfortunately, ddwrt:TodayISO() doesn't include the timezone offset, so you still need to monkey around to include that.

Alternatively, you can just do the date comparison in one xsl:when and compare the times only if you need to because the dates match.

Comment: Thanks Marc, James comments got me on the right track and was able to get it as you were writing this up.